# What`s a blocks coinbase value?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, value

Under the bitcoin Protocol rules here:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#Transactions

in the ["block" messages section](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22block.22_messages)
There is the pseudo-algorithm for validating a given block.

On Point 16-2 It says:

"Reject if coinbase value > sum of block creation fee and transaction fees"

If we keep it simple,

- I know that the block creation fee is calculated using 64 bit integer operations (in satoshis) as:

  (50 * 100000000) >> (height / 210000)
- And I also know that transaction fees are defined as:

  the sum of input values minus sum of output values for a given transaction.

So the overall transaction fees on a block would be the total sum of all transaction fees in that block.

But how do I 'calculate' in pseudo-words, the **coinbase value** and what is it referring to?

I seem to not understand something here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't the coinbase value in that comparison the value of the outputs of the first transaction (coinbase) in the block?

Comment: Yeah, it's the sum of the output amounts of the coinbase transaction (first transaction in a block).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coinbase value in that comparison is the sum of the amounts of the outputs of the first transaction (coinbase) in the block

<sub>(community wiki answer, to avoid having unanswered questions with answers in comments floating around and occasionally getting bumped to the homepage)</sub>